# NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)V

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Getting the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
```

when running

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/ocs/browserDrivers/chromedriver.exe");
//ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
//chromeOptions.addArguments("start-maximized");
driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Upgraded to selenium 3.14 and chromedriver 2.42.Not a maven project

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error message...

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
```

...implies that there was an error raised while executing the line:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/ocs/browserDrivers/chromedriver.exe");
```

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the *WebDriver* binary type and the underlying *Operating System*.

You need download, extract and use the right format of the *WebDriver* binary from [chromedriver.storage](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.42/) for your program as follows:

- Linux OS:

  ```
  chromedriver_linux64.tar.gz 2018-09-13 19:30:37 3.85MB
  ```
- MAC OS:

  ```
  chromedriver_mac64.tar.gz   2018-09-13 18:14:11 5.75MB
  ```
- Windows OS:

  ```
  chromedriver_win32.zip  2018-09-13 21:11:33 3.42MB
  ```

If you are using *MAC OS* so the `System.setProperty()` line would be:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/ocs/browserDrivers/chromedriver"); //drop the extension (.exe) part
```

If you are using *Windows OS* so the `System.setProperty()` line would be:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\path\\to\\chromedriver.exe"); //mention the absolute path
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I'm already using Chromedriver 2.24 for Chrome 69 and Selenium 3.14. Using a Windows machine. Still getting the same error message though

Comment: @Laura Checkout my answer update and let me know the status

Comment: Ensure you are using the latest `Chromedriver v2.42` binary.

Comment: Still same issue when changing the path... not sure what other dependency could be causing this issue

Comment: You can also remove all the jars and simply add the _selenium-server-standalone-3.14.0.jar_

Comment: It finally worked, re-added all the selenium libraries and check all the dependencies in the project, there was one in conflict. Thanks for your help !